# Equations of a line to say if they are parallel or perpendicular

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

How to show which lines are parallel and which are perpendicular. Any formulas or methods to do it?

> (b) Which lines are parallel? Give a reason for your answer.
>
> (c) Which lines are perpendicular? Give a reason for your answer.
>
> Line $1$: $y=3x-8$
>
> Line $2$: $y=1.5x-4$
>
> Line $3$: $y=9x+10$
>
> Line $4$: $y=3x+10$
>
> Line $5$: $y=-0.5x+7$
>
> Line $6$: $y=2x+8$

Comment: No reason to shout.

Comment: Sorry anyway do you know how to solve it ?

Comment: I can't really flip my head,can you consider flipping the images? Do you have any material that you can study/find formulas?

Comment: Please edit your question and write the question up in MathJax. Failing that at least reduce the image sizes and orient them properly so that I don't have to rotate my computer to read it.

Comment: It's expected on here to retype the question in Latex/MathJax and to explain what you have tried. It's not really reasonable to make minimum effort and then expect people to do your homework for you.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean anyone to be offended I'm studying for exams and this is not my homework it's past exam papers I use to revise and I just joined today so I'all make sure in future to flip the images sorry again I'm really glad though to see Poole helping me despite the way I write my questions

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

If we ensure each equation is in the form $y=mx+c$ then we can easily compare the gradients of the equations. *(Note: in your question they are all in this form, I'm including this comment for completeness)*

For lines to be parallel, the gradients will be the same (i.e. the value of $m$ is the same in each equation)

For lines to be perpendicular, the gradients will be opposite reciprocals (in other words, multiplying the two gradients ($m$ values) together will give you $-1$).

---

An example from your question:

Lines $1$ and $4$ are parallel as they both have $m=3$

Lines $5$ and $6$ are perpendicular as $-0.5\times2=-1$

Comment: This is the best help I've gotten thank you and I hope that'll you'll stick around from more questions from me I seem to understand your steps way better than my teachers thanks again

Comment: @Aurelia No worries, glad I could help. As you are new you may not be aware that you can accept the answer you deem to be best by clicking the tick mark next to the answer. This means it will be pinned at the top and other people will be able to see the best answer first

Comment: Yeah I just joined today and I don't understand why my posts are getting minuses beside them ? And sure thing I will do it now :) thanks again

Comment: It shows it won't show on public because I have less than 15 reputation but I've clicked it :)

Comment: @Aurelia The minuses mean that people have downvoted your question for various reasons. It is usually accepted that you add some of your own thoughts to the question and explain where and why you are stuck which could be where some of your downvotes are coming from. Some people may also not like your use of images - if you type out your question, then it shows you have put in some effort so people are more likely to put in the effort to help you

Comment: @Aurelia That's OK, you can always come back and acccept answers when you have got enough reputation

Comment: I see I didn't realise the rules here I guess I had no on clue how to start the question for my exam revision and when I saw that you can add pictures I though it would be easier for others :/

Comment: @Aurelia That's OK, you have to learn from somewhere! And now you know for future questions. And this site is definitely useful if you know how to jump through the hoops to write a good question. You might want to look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) too, which shows you how to write Maths nicely when you get to that point.

Comment: Thank you  Your really kind to me despite how I wrote my questions others are a bit sarcastic and I see they are really offended my how I asked them , well I hope you'll stick around to help me further in more nicely written questions ehhehe thanks again

Comment: @Aurelia No worries, and I don't see the point of being rude to new users - everyone has to learn from somewhere and we were all in your boat at some point. I'll keep an eye out for any new questions you post and good luck with the exams

Answer (score 0):

Lines are parallel if the slopes are the same and they are not coincident.  Lines are perpendicular if the slopes multiply to form $-1$.  Look through the list with this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Because all of the equations are of the form $y=mx+b$, it is sufficient to determine whether the lines are parallel by looking at the slope $m$.

Lines are parallel if they have equal slope $m$, such as $y=4x+2$ and $y=4x+8$.

Lines are perpendicular if the slopes are a negative reciprocal of each other. Namely, $m_1 = -\frac{1}{m_2}$ as in the example $y=4x+2$ and $y=-\frac{1}{4}x+7$.